# Creating a 2D Cylinder with Java Graphics

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a cylinder using Java Graphics and the paintComponent() method.
The user of the application can select which shape they want (in this case it's a cylinder) and input the dimensions they want for the shape.
After they input the dimensions and click the submit button, another window will open with the image drawn on it.

My current issue is getting the shape made correctly. I'm currently trying to make two ovals and connect them using two lines. The base will be a red oval and everything else will have no color.

When you submit the dimensions for the cylinder, the sides are never the correct length or in the correct position on the Y-Axis. An example can be view here:
[image: Cylinder with incorrect sides]

The dimensions for this cylinder: 200 height, 50 radius.

What the cylinder *should* look like:
[image]

300 height, 300 radius

I'll be working on adding the minimal version of the program for testing. However, for right now I'll be providing what the code is for the cylinder itself and the paintComponent() method.

Cylinder:

```
    import java.awt.Color;

public class Cylinder extends Circle {
    private int length;

    public Cylinder(int radius, int length, Color color) {
        super(radius, length, color);
        this.length = length;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    
    public Cylinder(int newX, int newY, int newRadius, int newLength) {
        super(newX, newY, newRadius);
        length = newLength;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public int calcArea() {
        return (int) Math.ceil( 2 * 3.14 * radius * radius + 2 * 3.14 * radius * length);
    }

    public int calcVolume() {
        return (int) Math.ceil(3.14 * radius * radius * length);
    }
    
    public DrawFigure drawFigure() {
        DrawFigure cylinder1 = new DrawFigure(4, getRadius(), length);
        return cylinder1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Length = " + length + " " + super.toString();
    } 
}
```

DrawFigure (paintComponent is the last method):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawFigure extends JPanel {
    int type;
    int length, width, height, radius;
    
    public DrawFigure() {
        super();
        type = 5;
    }
    
    public DrawFigure(int myType, int myWidth, int myLength, int myHeight) { // Box and Rectangle
        super();
        type = myType;
        length = myLength;
        width = myWidth;
        height = myHeight;
    }
    
    public DrawFigure(int x, int y, int myType, int myWidth, int myLength, int myHeight) {
        super();
        type = myType;
        length = myLength;
        width = myWidth;
        height = myHeight;
    }

    
    public DrawFigure(int myType, int myRadius, int myHeight) {
        super();
        type = myType;
        radius = myRadius;
        height = myHeight;
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        if (type == 1) { // Draw Rectangle

        } else if (type == 2) { // Draw Box

        } else if(type == 3) { // Draw Circle
            
        } else if(type == 4) { // Draw Cylinder
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawOval(135,  65, radius, radius - radius / 2);
            
            // Base
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(135, 65 + height, radius, radius / 2);
            
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(135, 65 + height + (height /4), 135, 135);
            
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(135 + radius, 65 + height + (height /4), 135 + radius, 135);
            return;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Full code for the program:

- Point.java https://pastebin.com/iVgN47e3
- Lab6GUI.java https://pastebin.com/bKM790iQ
- Rectangle.java https://pastebin.com/MdCrJYeA
- Box.java https://pastebin.com/iZCZpUi7
- Circle.java https://pastebin.com/aui1NgJi
- Cylinder.java https://pastebin.com/fHDNmBXT
- DrawFigure.java https://pastebin.com/z8t31put
- LessThanOrEqualToZeroException.java https://pastebin.com/4ELEmsNX
- LessThanOrGreaterThanException.java https://pastebin.com/1avRUudN

Comment: Can you provide the full code? Maybe here or someplace else. It will greatly help with testing.

Comment: I have added the full code for the program. Posted to pastebin to prevent the post from getting cluttered and too long

Comment: `public class Cylinder extends Circle`, that looks weird. A cylinder is not a circle.

Comment: @RageDeltaz Please add your code to the question itself, not on an external site. Reduce the code to a [mcve].

Comment: *"300 height, 300 radius"* ITYM diameter there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so drawing an oval extends from the `x`/`y` position, with a positive width/height, that would make the oval draw right/down from the `x`/`y` position, for example...

[image]

So, assuming we start at `0x0`, this would mean that the lines would need to start at a `y` position of `radius / 4`, given that you're using `radius` for the width and `radius / 2` for the height (I'm not going to mention how that is confusing).  This will allow the lines to "appear" that they join the outer edge of the oval (and draw down)

The lines would then be `height` long.  This means the bottom oval would then need to start at `height - (radius / 4)` ... okay, I had to go and double check this, but remember, the line ends at `(radius / 4) + height`, this also means that the cylinder is the `height + (radius / 2)` high in total.

### `height=200`, `radius=50`

[image]

### `height=300`, `radius=300`

[image]

This prevents scenario where `radius / 4` is greater than `height`, because that would just be a mess

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new DrawPane(300, 300));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        int height, radius;

        public DrawPane(int myRadius, int myHeight) {
            super();
            radius = myRadius;
            height = myHeight;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int x = (getWidth() - radius) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - (height + (radius / 4))) / 2;

            g2d.translate(x, y);

            g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g2d.drawRect(0, 0, radius, height + (radius / 4));

            // Base
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillOval(0, height - (radius / 4), radius, radius / 2);

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawOval(0, 0, radius, radius / 2);

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawLine(0, radius / 4, 0, height);
            g2d.drawLine(radius, radius / 4, radius, height);

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```